# Troubleshooting IPMI on Celestix Appliance

Tags: ipmi, ipmitool, ipmiutil

I'm trying set an IPMI address on an application sitting in a remote data center. I can set the address, but I can't ping or connect over HTTP/HTTPS once set. The IPMI version is based on http://ipmiutil.sourceforge.net/.

I've tried the commands below, but no luck so far:

1. Setting the IP manually

`Clxipmiutil lan -e -u root -p thisisnottherealpassword -I 10.8.2.56  -S 255.255.0.0 -G 10.8.210.1`

2. Setting the IP manually and supplying the gateway MAC.

`Clxipmiutil lan -e -u root -p thisisnottherealpassword -I 10.8.2.56  -S 255.255.0.0 -G 10.8.210.1 -H 00-00-0d-9f-f0-ca`

3. Using DHCP

`Clxipmiutil lan -u root -p thisisnottherealpassword -D`

4. Using DHCP and supplying the MAC

`Clxipmiutil lan -e -u root -p thisisnottherealpassword -D -G 10.8.210.1 -H 00-00-0d-9f-f0-ca`

Any advice would be helpful. Configuration details below.

> C:>Clxipmiutil lan -u root -p thisisnottherealpassword -D ipmiutil
>   ver 2.11 pefconfig ver 2.11
>   -- BMC version 1.0, IPMI version 2.0
>
> pefconfig: GetPefEntry ...
>
> PEFilter(01): ff Other event - enabled for alert
>
> PEFilter(02): ff Other event - enabled for alert
>
> PEFilter(03): ff Other event - enabled for alert
>
> PEFilter(04): ff Other event - enabled for alert
>
> PEFilter(05): ff Other event - enabled for alert
>
> PEFilter(06): ff Other event - enabled for alert
>
> PEFilter(07): ff Other event - enabled for alert
>
> PEFilter(08): ff Other event - enabled for alert
>
> PEFilter(09): ff Other event - enabled for alert
>
> PEFilter(10): ff Other event - enabled for alert
>
> PEFilter(11): ff Other event - enabled for alert
>
> PEFilter(12): ff Other event - enabled for no action
>
> PEFilter(13): ff Other event - enabled for no action
>
> PEFilter(14): ff Other event - enabled for no action
>
> PEFilter(15): 20 OS Critical Stop event - enabled for alert
>
> PEFilter(16): 09 Power Unit event - enabled for alert
>
> PEFilter(17): 09 Power Unit event - enabled for alert
>
> PEFilter(18): 09 Power Unit event - enabled for alert
>
> PEFilter(19): 09 Power Unit event - enabled for alert
>
> PEFilter(20): 09 Power Unit event - enabled for alert
>
> PEF Control: 01 PEFenable
>
> PEF Actions: 1f Alert PwrDn Reset PwrCyc OEM
>
> PEF Startup Delay: 0 sec
>
> PEF Alert Startup Delay: 0 sec
>
> PEF Alert Policy[1]: 01 00 00 00 Disabled
>
> PEF Alert Policy[2]: 02 00 00 00 Disabled
>
> PEF Alert Policy[3]: 03 00 00 00 Disabled
>
> PEF Alert Policy[4]: 04 00 00 00 Disabled
>
> pefconfig: GetLanEntry for channel 8 ...
>
> Lan Param(0) Set in progress: 00
>
> Lan Param(1) Auth type support: 37 None MD2 MD5 Pswd OEM
>
> Lan Param(2) Auth type enables: 16 16 16 16 00
>
> Lan Param(3) IP address: 10 8 2 56
>
> Lan Param(4) IP addr src: 02 DHCP
>
> Lan Param(5) MAC addr: 00 01 69 01 bc 07
>
> Lan Param(6) Subnet mask: 255 255 0 0
>
> Lan Param(7) IPv4 header: 40 40 10
>
> Lan Param(10) BMC grat ARP : 01
>
> Lan Param(11) grat ARP interval: 04
>
> Lan Param(12) Def gateway IP: 10 8 210 1
>
> Lan Param(13) Def gateway MAC: 00 00 0d 9f f0 ca
>
> Lan Param(14) Sec gateway IP: 0 0 0 0
>
> Lan Param(15) Sec gateway MAC: 00 00 00 00 00 00
>
> Lan Param(16) Community string: AMI
>
> Lan Param(17) Num dest: 0f
>
> Lan Param(18) Dest type: 00 00 00 00 00
>
> Lan Param(18) Dest type: 00 00 00 00 00
>
> Lan Param(18) Dest type: 00 00 00 00 00
>
> Lan Param(18) Dest type: 00 00 00 00 00
>
> Lan Param(18) Dest type: 00 00 00 00 00
>
> Lan Param(18) Dest type: 00 00 00 00 00
>
> Lan Param(18) Dest type: 00 00 00 00 00
>
> Lan Param(18) Dest type: 00 00 00 00 00
>
> Lan Param(18) Dest type: 00 00 00 00 00
>
> Lan Param(18) Dest type: 00 00 00 00 00
>
> Lan Param(18) Dest type: 00 00 00 00 00
>
> Lan Param(18) Dest type: 00 00 00 00 00
>
> Lan Param(18) Dest type: 00 00 00 00 00
>
> Lan Param(18) Dest type: 00 00 00 00 00
>
> Lan Param(18) Dest type: 00 00 00 00 00
>
> Lan Param(19) Dest address: 01 00 00 [0 0 0 0] 00 00 00 00
>
> Lan Param(19) Dest address: 02 00 00 [0 0 0 0] 00 00 00 00
>
> Lan Param(19) Dest address: 03 00 00 [0 0 0 0] 00 00 00 00
>
> Lan Param(19) Dest address: 04 00 00 [0 0 0 0] 00 00 00 00
>
> Lan Param(19) Dest address: 00 00 00 [0 0 0 0] 00 00 00 00
>
> Lan Param(19) Dest address: 00 00 00 [0 0 0 0] 00 00 00 00
>
> Lan Param(19) Dest address: 00 00 00 [0 0 0 0] 00 00 00 00
>
> Lan Param(19) Dest address: 00 00 00 [0 0 0 0] 00 00 00 00
>
> Lan Param(19) Dest address: 00 00 00 [0 0 0 0] 00 00 00 00
>
> Lan Param(19) Dest address: 00 00 00 [0 0 0 0] 00 00 00 00
>
> Lan Param(19) Dest address: 00 00 00 [0 0 0 0] 00 00 00 00
>
> Lan Param(19) Dest address: 00 00 00 [0 0 0 0] 00 00 00 00
>
> Lan Param(19) Dest address: 00 00 00 [0 0 0 0] 00 00 00 00
>
> Lan Param(19) Dest address: 00 00 00 [0 0 0 0] 00 00 00 00
>
> Lan Param(19) Dest address: 00 00 00 [0 0 0 0] 00 00 00 00
>
> GetLanEntry: completion code=80
>
> GetLanEntry(192), ret = -1
>
> Lan Param(193) DHCP MAC Address: 00 00 00 00 00 00
>
> Lan Param(194) DHCP Enable: 01
>
> GetChanAcc(lan), ret = 0, new value = 22   Access = Always Avail, PEF
>   Alerts Disabled
>
> Channel Access Mode(Lan): 22 04
>
> GetSOL for channel 8 ...
>
> SOL Enable: 01 enabled
>
> SOL Auth: 02 User
>
> SOL Accum Interval: 04 32  20 msec
>
> SOL Retry Interval: 06 14  200 msec
>
> SOL nvol Baud Rate: 07 19.2k
>
> SOL vol Baud Rate: 07 19.2k
>
> SOL Payload Access(8,2): 02 00 00 00 enabled
>
> SOL Payload Support(8): 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>
> Get User Access(1): 0a 81 02 54 IPMI, Admin  ()
>
> Get User Access(2): 0a 41 02 54 IPMI, Admin  (root)
>
> Get User Access(3): 0a 81 02 0f No access ()
>
> Get User Access(4): 0a 81 02 0f No access () pefconfig: completed
>   successfully
>
> C:>

Answer (score 0):

Use the commands below

IPMI reset - clxipmiutil cmd 00 20 18 02
 IPMI Reboot - clxipmiutil cmd 00 20 18 03
 To Force the IP assignment to static mode - Clxipmiutil cmd 00 20 30 01 01 04 01

IPMI - does the job, but you're better off paying a few extra ££ and going with ILO or DRAC